# Help Finding A Book

Tags: orbital-mechanics, crewed-spaceflight, reentry, engineering

I am trying to find the book that contains the following chapter: https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/media/III.4.1.1_Space_in_our_lives.pdf

I would appreciate it if someone let's me know the name of the book and the title! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: Understanding Space: An Introduction to Astronautics, by Jerry Jon Sellers. McGraw-Hill, 2000.

I picked a sentence that seemed sufficiently unique, "The poetic reasons are embodied in the quotation at the beginning of this
chapter.", and searched for it in Google Books, and it returned a [single hit](https://books.google.com/books?id=kZNTAAAAMAAJ&q=%22The%20poetic%20reasons%20are%20embodied%20in%20the%20quotation%20at%20the%20beginning%20of%20this%20chapter.%22&dq=%22The%20poetic%20reasons%20are%20embodied%20in%20the%20quotation%20at%20the%20beginning%20of%20this%20chapter.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj0vSqnq7kAhVGrZ4KHUwRD7cQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg).

Comment: That's the book! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be an online tutorial on the FAA website. Start at the FAA's page [Advanced Aerospace Medicine On-line](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/):

> The text is divided into three sections. To locate a specific topic click on the section, then the topic, and the material will appear.
>
> - [Section I - The Aerospace Environment](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/section1/)
> - [Section II - Aviation Operations](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/section2/)
> - [Section III - Space Operations](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/section3/)

click [Section III - Space Operations](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/section3/) which takes you to:

> **Advanced Aerospace Medicine On-line**
>
> Section III - Space Operations

- [Space Physiology and Medicine](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/section3/space_physiology/)
- [Medical Issues of Specific Space Operations](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/section3/medical_issues/)
- [Space Human Factors Issues](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/section3/space_hf/)
- [Basic Concepts of Manned Spacecraft Design](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/section3/spacecraft_design/)
- [Environmental Impact of Space Operations](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/section3/environmental_impact/)

Click [Basic Concepts of Manned Spacecraft Design](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/section3/spacecraft_design/) which takes you to the following list where the first one is your link. I won't take the time to add all the other hyperlinks, but they're there.

> **Advanced Aerospace Medicine On-line**
>
> Section III - Space Operations
>
> Basic Concepts of Manned Spacecraft Design

- [4.1.1 Space in Our Lives (PDF)](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/media/III.4.1.1_Space_in_our_lives.pdf)
- 4.1.2 The Space Environment (PDF)
- 4.1.3 Understanding Orbits (PDF)
- 4.1.4 Describing Orbits (PDF)
- 4.1.5 Maneuvering in Space (PDF)
- 4.1.6 Interplanetary Travel (PDF)
- 4.1.7 Returning from Space (PDF)
- 4.2.1 Rockets and Launch Vehicles (PDF)
- 4.3.1 Space Vehicle Control Systems (PDF)
- 4.4.1 Environmental Control and Life-Support Subsystems (ECLSS) (PDF)

Some of those, including section 4.1.1 show an interesting name in the browser tab:

[image]

---

Possible sources?

> References
>
> Canuto, Vittorio and Carlos Chagas. *The Impact of Space Exploration on Mankind*. Pontificaia Academia Scientiarum, proceedings of a study week held October 1–5, 1984, Ex Aedibus Academicis In Civitate Vaticana, 1986.
>
> Wertz, James R. and Wiley J. Larson. *Space Mission Analysis and Design. Third edition. Dordrecht, Netherlands: Kluwer Academic Publishers, 1999.
>
> Wilson, Andrew (ed.), Space Directory 1990–91. Jane’s information group. Alexandria, VA, 1990.

Comment: They showed the wrong toilet (p. 4.4.1-448) lol